# How to regenerate indexes after removing element

Tags: javafx, refresh

I am having simple vbox which will have six hboxes and I can delete one/all and add once again.

My code :

```
@FXML
private VBox userSelectedValues;

int index = userSelectedValues.getChildren().indexOf(event.getSource()); 

userSelectedValues.getChildren().remove(cnt);
ObservableList<Node> hboxNodes = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
hboxNodes.addAll(userSelectedValues.getChildren());
userSelectedValues.getChildren().clear();
userSelectedValues.getChildren().addAll(hboxNodes);
```

Scenario : there are six elements initially

1) I deleted 4th element - works fine - now total 5 elements
2) I deleted 3rd element - works fine - now total 4 elements
3) Now if I want to delete 6th element is giving me the indexOutOfBoutnd which is expected.

So how to regenerate or refresh indexes.

Thank you,

Comment: At step-3, where do you get the index=6, are you storing indices somewhere or hardcoded?

Comment: I am not storing indexes but I am having one variable that gives me the indexex ---> "cnt".

Comment: Why that variable is giving index=6 while there are 4 items left?

Comment: No, It will never get index 6 becuase I am having restriction that user can add only 6 rows. So sixth row has index 5.

And after removing upper elements, if I go to delete last element then IndexOutOfBound error comes.

Comment: Sorry I meant index=5 above. So again while there are 4 items left, now the max index=3. How index=5 is returned?

Comment: That is the problem I have. First I removed 3rd element which has index 2, right? So my stack has 0,1,3,4,5 indexes. After I removed 5th element, so index 3rd deleted, right? And if I want to delete my sixth element it is giving me indexoutofbound error that size=3 and index=5 something. I hope this makes you clearer.

Comment: Have you seen the answer below? Have you tried to understand it? When you remove the item from the list, all items after the removed one will have update their indexes. So "First I removed 3rd element which has index 2, So my stack has 0,1,3,4,5 indexes." is wrong, you will have  0,1,2,3,4 indexes.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "refresh" indexes? The children are in an ObservableList. If you remove an item, then the indexes change.

Example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        HBox root = new HBox();

        Label label1 = new Label( "Label1");
        Label label2 = new Label( "Label2");
        Label label3 = new Label( "Label3");

        root.getChildren().addAll( label1, label2, label3);

        System.out.println( "Original:");

        System.out.println(label1.getText() + ": " + root.getChildren().indexOf(label1));
        System.out.println(label2.getText() + ": " + root.getChildren().indexOf(label2));
        System.out.println(label3.getText() + ": " + root.getChildren().indexOf(label3));


        root.getChildren().remove(label2);

        System.out.println( "Modified:");

        System.out.println(label1.getText() + ": " + root.getChildren().indexOf(label1));
        System.out.println(label2.getText() + ": " + root.getChildren().indexOf(label2));
        System.out.println(label3.getText() + ": " + root.getChildren().indexOf(label3));


        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The 2nd item is removed, the console output is as expected:

```
Original:
Label1: 0
Label2: 1
Label3: 2

Modified:
Label1: 0
Label2: -1
Label3: 1
```

According to the documentation about [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in
>   this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.

Comment: You can add an explanation of the -1, otherwise it may be misleading.

Comment: Ok, added the indexOf reference.